# Filter Partners Accounting Report [Odoo12]

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I am trying to filter the partner list on an odoo accounting report (Partner Ledger) located on *Accounting-> Reporting -> Partner Ledger*

[image]

I need to set default list to display only customer partner (customer_rank = 1),not all contacts as it is displaying right now.

**Is there a way to filter that list?**

I was trying to find the view displayed below, but I couldn't find any view to change the context or domain.

[image]

Also I tried through JS but I do not see any way to add domain on button (account_reports module).

```
<div class="col-12">
  <t t-if="options.get('partner_ids') != None">
    Partners:
    <t t-set="res_partner_value">All</t>
    <t t-foreach="options['selected_partner_ids']" t-as="partner_name">
      <t t-set="res_partner_value" t-value="''"/>
      <t t-esc="partner_name"/>
    </t>
    <t t-esc="res_partner_value"/>
  </t>
</div>
```

Comment: You can create custom filter and then set the same as default .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution:

There is a function on the js file, where you can pass a **domain** field when creating a widget:

```
name: fieldName,
relation: fieldInfo.modelName,
type: 'many2many',
domain: "[('customer_rank','=',1)]",
value: fieldInfo.value
```

After adding that, the partner list is filtered as expected.